# How to disconnect from socketio4net

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io, socketio4net, websocket4net

I have a application that connecting from c# client to node.js server
in c# client I am using socketio4net and websocket4net
in server I using nodejs and socket.io

when I close my program (c#), disconnect event was not sent to server.
so I got error:

socket error Error: read ECONNRESET at errnoExeption (net.js: 558:19)

but if i am using socket.io client (javascript) instead of c# when I close browser, everything work well
this is my code:

server.js:

```
var io= require('socket.io').listen(3000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    // handle here
    })
})
```

c# client:

```
client = new Client("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
socket = client.Connect();
```

javascript client:

```
io.connect("127.0.0.1:3000");
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an old question, but I actually had this issue yesterday so I might as well post it. Solution was to create an event for onClose of the program and call socket.Close().

For me, I'm using WPF so in my xaml:

> <Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow" ... Closing="Window_Closing">

And in code behind:

> private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
>   {
>      socket.Close();
>   }